# How to get normal/displacement/ao maps for a part of a photo

Tags: texturing

So I used a tool to create maps from a photo, turned out that the map of a cut out shape of the photo completes itself with the rest of the photo.

This is very bad, is there another way to get maps for a part of a photo?

Just the photo:

[image: Texture photo]

Normal map from it:

[image: Texture normal map]

The cut out shape:

[image: cut out part]

The normal map of the shape with autocompleted parts and a strange border on top:

[image: cut out normal]

An example with another shape which I only imported like this:

[image: another shape]

Its normal map is as it should be:

[image: another shape normal]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not abot blender but other sotware

Comment: As you wish, it was answered quite perfect by TLousky anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about generating maps in crazybump

Comment: It kind of is... yet the answer is about the maps in general. And the question could be seen too in relation to the answer.

Comment: Tried to reword it, maybe someone else will also need a reminder of simple graphic design techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't bother you much, since you probably have the original cut image, with all the removed parts transparent (?)

In that case you can use the alpha to either make a mask / selection and remove the useless bits from the generated maps in photoshop / gimp,

Or you can use the alpha from the cut color map in color mix nodes in the node editor. Either way it won't have any effect.

Comment: Of course! I can just cut the shape out of the maps. Thanks man, I was too stupid to come up with this easy solution lol

Comment: Sometimes the obvious stuff is the most elusive, happens to me all the time :)

Comment: It is even better since the normal map of a cut out shape gets "corrupted" by the background.